# Why does "align-items: baseline" not working in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I am having trouble creating a consistent flexbox between Chrome, Edge, IE and Firefox in my VUE application. The css I have works great in Chrome, Edge and Firefox but fails for Internet Explorer 11 .

I have a header in which I show two containers, one of them wrapping two logos and the other container wraps a list of links and dropdowns with links.
here a simplified outline of my template

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light header" v-if="!paymentIsSelected">
                  <div class="branding-wrapper">
                    <a v-bind:href="this.url">
                    <div class="logo-icon">
                    <svg role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 114.4 129.32"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo-text">
                     <svg role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 278.41 53.09"></svg>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav menu">
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </nav>
            </header>
         </div>
     </div>
</template>
```

and here's mi css

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline !important;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 1.75rem;
  padding-right: 1.75rem;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.branding-wrapper {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.branding-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.branding-wrapper .logo-icon {
  width: 60px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.branding-wrapper .logo-text {
  width: 150px;
}

.branding-wrapper .logo-icon,
.branding-wrapper .logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.branding-wrapper .logo-icon svg, 
.branding-wrapper .logo-text svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  fill: $secondaryColor;
}
```

in addition to not applying the "align-items: baseline" In the "branding-wrapper" container, I apply an inline-block to both logos and they are shown aligned at the bottom in all browsers except IE.

I have searched for other references to the subject and I have tried to declare a height to the header as indicated but it doesn't work and also to include a script in the index.html but it doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: It isn't supported in IE See [Browser Compatibility for `align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @FluffyKitten and what would be the alternative for this browser?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the FluffyKitten that align-items: baseline is not supported in the IE and that's why it is not working in the IE browser.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT but now the question is, what is the alternative? i can't find a way to adjust it for internet explorer and i have tried all the solutions i have found

Comment: @FluffyKitten but now the question is, what is the alternative? i can't find a way to adjust it for internet explorer and i have tried all the solutions i have found

Comment: @javascript110899, When I try to run your sample code in the IE it shows some ul bullets. In chrome, it just shows the blank page. If you can show the picture of what result you want to get in the IE browser then we can try to find an alternative solution. Thanks for your understanding.